# Pyglet: equivalent of pygame.Rect

Tags: collision, pyglet, rect

I am contemplating migrating from pygame to pyglet (main reason: move from Python to Pypy). However, I found no rectangle collision tools in the pyglet doc, while I use pygame.Rect quite often.

Do you know how pyglet deals with rectangle collision (maybe with OpenGl funcs, but I do not know them) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Pyglet doesn't not have this system. You will have to implement it on your own. You could possibly import just pygame's rect and use it within pyglet.

Pyglet is only an opengl interface, not a game toolkit.

(this was a hurdle for me way back when, but you'll get over it. stick with it, pyglet is the right direction to go from pygame)

Comment: Thank you. I am still afraid that pygame.Rect will not run under Pypy, so that I should rewrite it...